# use set to subtract the column value in update query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-update

I am working on a database column value (int) to subtract and update using `set`.

I am using `$this->db->set()` to subtract and update column value in codeigniter.

The problem is when I run the query the column value get change to null.

```
$this->db->set('app_balance', 'app_balance'. - $app_work_charge.'');
$this->db->where('id', $app_id);
$this->db->update('app');
```

In my log file it will not showing any error.

More Explanation: if column value is 200 and if I will want to subtract 10 from it then after query execution it will change to `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `false` at the end of the first line and put `-` after field name.

```
$this->db->set('app_balance', 'app_balance-'. $app_work_charge.'',false);
$this->db->where('id', $app_id);
$this->db->update('app');
```

Comment: thanks, i am not getting what this `false` do? can you please elaborate in little detail.

Comment: `false`  will prevent data from being escaped.
you can also refer other details from `https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html`